# How do you prevent a WebView from cropping the web content?

Tags: ios, webview

I thought the content would wrap to fit inside the WebView, but instead the right hand side is clipped off.
Sorry for asking such a noob question (WV should just wrap!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping would be done in the **HTML5 webpage**, as it understands the device(PC or Mobile) and behaves accordingly, for others you need special webpage e.g. (**m.facebook.com** which acts as interface for mobile and www.facebook.com for PCs).

For displaying the complete screen in single screen webview(scaled down) use the following code

```
yourWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```